# UIApplication Instance fail

Tags: ios, swift

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    // FAIL
}
```

But If I do `UIApplication.shared.delegate` then I'm getting `Optional<UIApplicationDelegate>`

Please help.

AppDelegate: https://gist.github.com/n1tesh/8f069e3b4eb9d843e691f5d463b81017

Comment: can you show your `AppDelegate` class?

Comment: @Kamran Updated question with gist. Please check.

Comment: can you show error description

Comment: @mohsen It returns NIL

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-ios-sdk/issues/2), if you are using some framework that does things like in the link.

Comment: @NITESH look up to the link. Coz u faced problems after CleverTap integration.

Answer (score 0):

with  `UIApplication.shared.delegate` you are getting

`Optional<UIApplicationDelegate>` is actually protocol, and  with this line

`if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {`

you are checking that some class named  `AppDelegate` is confirming that protocol. If your `if` condition fails that means that your AppDelegate is not confirm  `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol methods. and not related but  also confirm `@UIApplicationMain` is there in top of AppDelegate class

Comment: how to confirm that ?

Comment: @NITESH Please add your appdelegate code in question

Comment: I think this happened after CleverTap Implementation. Earlier it was working fine.